# Itunes on Ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, itunes

I really need to get Itunes on Ubuntu for jailbreaking purposes, but none of the other solutions on this website seem to work. I have Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) on my HP Chromebook 14, but I have recently discovered that Itunes only works on 32 bit versions of Ubuntu. I have wine installed and have downloaded the 64 bit version of Itunes but it still doesn't work. I also have playonlinux but when I download it from there it asks me to download the 32 bit version from Apple's website. So I do and when it finishes installing nothing happens and it crashes.

Please show me how to get Itunes on a 64 bit version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Comment moved to this answer.

iTunes does not work on Ubuntu even via Wine or PlayOnLinux anymore.

You will need to set up a Windows VM on your system, install iTunes in that, and set up USB pass through so the device can be connected to it via USB.

Short of this, or using a Windows box there is no other solution to make iTunes work, and believe me I have tried.